# Problem with translating sets into logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm starting to work through Munkres and in the first section there is an easy excercise that I have problem with when I'm formalizing it.

The quesiton asks if the iff is valid or if not which way the implication runs

$A \subset B \ \lor A \subset C \stackrel{?}{\iff} A \subset (B \ \cup C)$

It is obvious that if the A is subset of either B or C that it will be subset of their sum. Other way round it doesn't work as we can have A being a subset of elements of both B and C resulting in it being a subset of neither individually.

This is my attempt to write it formally.

1. $(x \in A \implies x \in B) \ \lor \ (x \in A \implies x \in C)$  // Rewriting the left hand site using implications
2. $(x \notin A \ \lor x \in B) \ \lor \ (x \notin A \ \lor x \in C)$ // Material implication
3. $(x \notin A \ \lor x \notin A) \ \lor \ (x \in B \ \lor x \in C)$ // Associativity
4. $x \notin A \ \lor \ (x \in B \ \lor x \in C)$ // Idempotency
5. $(x \in A \implies (x \in B \ \lor \ x \in C)$ // Material implication

But this would suggest that the implication is running both ways which is nonsense and means I am making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: As a minor terminological note, $A\cup B$ is usually called the union of $A$ and $B$. The "sum" of $A$ and $B$ usually refers to the *disjoint* union (or, in some algebraic contexts, it might refer to element-wise sum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to write the *quantifiers*:
$(A\subseteq B)$ means $\pmb{\forall x} :x\in A\implies x\in B$. 
With the quantifiers properly written, your proof works only in the forward direction.

Comment: Specifically $$\begin{array}{c}(A\subseteq B)\lor (A\subseteq C)\\\Updownarrow\\\forall x~(x\in A\to x\in B)\lor\forall x~(x\in A\to x\in C) \\\Downarrow&\bigstar\\\forall x~\big((x\in A\to x\in B)\lor(x\in A\to x\in C)\big)\\\Updownarrow\\\forall x~\big(x\in A\to(x\in B\lor x\in C)\big)\\\Updownarrow\\A\subseteq B\cup C&\end{array}$$